# Is there a way to analyze the load time of the functions in a custom plugin?

Tags: plugins, optimization

I have a custom plugin that is adding on average 1 second to the page load time. I thought the code was well written, but clearly not. Is there any way for me to find out what aspect of the plugin in particular is causing the slow loading?

If it could be broke down by function name it would allow me to think of some alternatives to speed this part of the plugin up.

Comment: Download and install Query Monitor plugin. It will return all queries with execution time

Comment: I would add [Debug Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) into the mix as another suggestion.